# Invariance of Lebesgue measure on unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on unit circle $S^1$ is invariant under mapping $T_{\alpha}:S^1\to S^1$, $T_{\alpha}(s)=s\cdot e^{2i\pi\alpha}$. I know it is not much, but honestly I completely do not know how to "bite" this task. First of all I have to show that we have for every set $A\in S^1$
$$
\lambda(T^{-1}(A)=\lambda(A).
$$

Comment: How do you define the measure? If you use the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ to construct is (as is done in Folland's book), then this property follows from the way the Lebesgue measure behaves with respect to linear operators (the weaker version of the change of variables formula).

Comment: I don't know... I thought about Pushforward measure $f_*(\lambda)(B)=\lambda(f^{-1}(B))$, where $f:[0,2\pi]\to S^1$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Could you tell me which of Folland's books are you referring to?